# Should you separate matrix data and math?

Tags: java, performance, math, linear-algebra

I am trying to make some simple classes to do the math necessary for OpenGL transformations. However, now that I am about halfway and while looking through different examples I find that most libraries keep the math separate of the matrix class itself (most of the times in math class with static methods). What exactly is the reason for this?

Is it when you're creating multiple of the matrix objects that the functions are also created multiple times, which impacts performance or something else entirely?

Example:
I find it much easier to add the math functions to the matrix class so I dont need to pass the matrix itself to the functions: e.g.

```
class Matrix4f {

    //constructor...

    public void rotate(double theta) {
        setValue(0, 0, (float) Math.cos(theta));
        setValue(1, 0, (float) Math.sin(theta));
        setValue(0, 1, (float) Math.sin(theta));
        setValue(1, 1, (float) Math.cos(theta));
    }

    //getters and setters...
}
```

instead of

```
public class LinearAlgebraMath {
    public static Matrix4f rotate(Matrix4f target, double theta) {
        target.setValue(0, 0, (float) Math.cos(theta));
        target.setValue(1, 0, (float) Math.sin(theta));
        target.setValue(0, 1, (float) Math.sin(theta));
        target.setValue(1, 1, (float) Math.cos(theta));
        return target;    
    }
}

public class Matrix4f {

    //constructor...

    //getters and setters...
}
```

So, in the end I like adding the math functions to the matrix class because it's easier for me (especially when dealing with dealing with math operations that use multiple data structures) but I don't want to have my preferences lower performance, so my question is: Does example below outperform the example above and if yes, why?

Comment: Note that you `rotate` does no rotation; it instead makes the matrix to be a rotation matrix. Adding methods to the class itself is usually much better as it's more OO and more common in Java. There's absolutely no performance difference. Just make sure you name them properly.

Comment: Isn't the use of static methods an attempt to avoid a garbage collection performance problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it when you're creating multiple of the matrix objects that the
>   functions are also created multiple times, which impacts performance
>   or something else entirely?

The functions are part of the `Class` object loaded into the VM. Multiple `Matrix` objects will only reference one copy of that function/method. So memory etc. will not be impacted by using instance methods as you're suggesting.

I'd normally attach the functionality to the instance of the class, as you're suggesting. Perhaps the references you're using were translated from a non-OO language (C?) where structures were used for the matrices and standalone functions were mandatory?

Comment: Thank you, it's indeed possible that its translated from C as they are for use with OpenGL.

Comment: I disagree with keeping data and logic in one class. I would keep Matrix4f class as an entity which holds data and create a service which performs calculations. What if you need to rotate different matrix? Would you create another type of matrix with its own rotate method...? It's better to factor your code into smaller classes.

Answer (score 0):

Nonmembers come with the practical benefit that they have looser coupling. They can't modify the internals of the class, so to speak.

As an example, if you ever come across a user-reported bug where the application threw a general array access out of bounds exception (not one specific to your matrix class) with code relating to matrices, then if you have a very simple matrix class that only has a few methods that can possibly mess with its genitalia (privates) and give it STDs, your list of suspects that your matrix has slept with is very narrow. Meanwhile if you have a matrix class with 200 methods where it's partying and getting drunk and sleeping with everything that has a hole, your list of suspects to investigate is huge.

It also comes with the benefit that you can achieve code stability (as in cemented in concrete, lacking reasons to change further) faster with your matrix class if it doesn't aim to provide every matrix-related operation known to man. That's very useful when designing anything to make sure the public interface has a point where it is truly "done" where you don't feel the temptation to go back and add more and more indefinitely to the point where you have some beast of a class that has 100+ methods with documentation that has to span 20 pages. It's good to be able to section off your codebase into stable (unchanging) vs. unstable (changing) parts, so with any design you should be able to achieve a state of "completeness" as far as what functionality it provides in a very finite 
amount of time.

Aiming to add every possible operation you can ever do with a class into the class itself will often make achieving such a goal impossible. The more and more you add to a class, the more and more you'll find reasons to add more. There's a vicious cycle there where the more you add, the more incomplete your design will seem. Minimalism is the way to counter that goal.

And finally it makes your matrix class easier to understand how to use when there's less things you can do with it off the bat. Some people might not be interested in eigenvectors/values and so it might help to make your interface more comprehensible if it provides fewer functions.

A pragmatic kind of approach is to include the basic operations into your design that people of all backgrounds do all the time, like matrix/matrix and matrix/vector multiplication. There you can still have a checklist where you can call the design "done" at some point without designing a god class/monolith that aims to do everything imaginable in the world. Then put the exotic stuff into separate interfaces, like separate classes with static methods which can only operate through the public interface of the matrix. Those separate static methods don't have access to the internals so they can go through, say, a layer of safety where your matrix class can impose invariants that disallow its internal data from being accessed out of bounds without throwing a `MatrixOutOfBounds` exception or something to this effect.

In your case I imagine it's just a more one-to-one translation with OpenGL which is a C API where methods are impossible, but it's worth noting that nonmembers are superior from a general software engineering standpoint of coupling and cohesion. They might be syntactically more cumbersome but the less things there are that can access your class's privates, the better from a maintenance and debugging standpoint. Too many methods and your privates become analogous to global variables because they have such an epic scope/visibility where so many things can potentially tamper with them. It's something to keep in mind when designing classes in any language -- to look for reasons to omit adding something directly to a class if it can be implemented elsewhere using only the public interface of that class. For similar reasons, if you can avoid inheriting from a class to access its protected members, composition is superior to inheritance in these contexts from an SE standpoint as it produces looser coupling.

From a performance standpoint there tend to be more reasons to add methods directly to a class since the most efficient solutions might require access to the class's internals. Still it's better to err on the side of adding a new method in hindsight when there's a strong perceived need for it than to add a boatload of needless methods to a class in advance. I like to go with the simple rule of "when in doubt, leave it out" when it comes to whether I should add a method to an interface or not.